# How do I invert a binary search tree?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Problem : https://leetcode.com/problems/invert-binary-tree/

My approach :

```
void getInorder(std::vector<int> & vec, TreeNode* root){
        if(root){
            getInorder(vec, root->left);
            vec.push_back(root->val);
            getInorder(vec, root->right);
        }
    }

    void setValues(TreeNode*  root, std::vector<int> &vec, int &i ){
        if(root){
            setValues(root->left, vec, i);
            root->val = vec[i];
            i--;
            setValues(root->right, vec, i);
        }
    }

    TreeNode* invertTree(TreeNode* root) {
        std::vector<int> inorderList, sol;
        getInorder(inorderList, root);
        int  i = inorderList.size() - 1;
        setValues(root, inorderList, i);
        getInorder(sol, root);
        return root;
    }
```

I am traversing the tree in inorder manner and I note down the values in a list. I again traverse the tree in inorder fashion but this time I start assigning values from the end of the list to the nodes. This should swap the left and right child values thus providing a decreasing sequence if you do inorder again.

The test case [1,2] fails. According to the logic it outputs [2,1] which seems right to me but the actual output is [1, null, 2]. I guess leetcode is doing a preorder traversal for the output, it is not very clear.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why screw with the tree at all?. Why not just have a separate proc, `getInorderR` that traverses the tree as right-mid-left rather than the traditional left-mid-right ?

Comment: I don't quite get what you are saying. Should the inorder be reversed with reverse-inorder?

Comment: There is a simpler solution that doesn't touch the values. Traverse the tree and swap the left and right pointer in each node.

Comment: Oh yes. I am trying to do it iteratively using a queue now. Leetcode’s output is a little too mysterious. For [1,2] as input they expect [1, null, 2] as the output. I am kinda lost there now.

Comment: It seems that there is a bug in your printing code, since the current code seems correct (assuming the input is really a search tree, which the problem does not state). Can you show the code that prints the final result?

Comment: Printing code? Which line?

Comment: The code that printed `[1, null, 2]`. Or does [1, null, 2] mean something else?

Comment: Oh. That is the output provided by leetcode for the input [1,2] without any explanation of how they got that output. Generally I have never seen null printed in the output of any kind of traversal as it is not useful information at all. I have no idea how they are getting that output and failing my code.

Comment: The original problem doesn't mention the word "search". A binary tree is not necessarily a binary search tree. Oh and while we're at it,
code at "leetcode" is not necessarily "leet".

Comment: I don’t understand what leet means in this context. And you are right. I didn’t pay attention that it was not necessarily a binary search tree.

Comment: [l33t](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=l33t).

Comment: Definitely. If only interviewers knew that and stopped torturing me. I can’t change their opinion on my own. I have gotta do what it takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code only changes the `val` fields, without changing the original topology. So a tree that looks like:

```
  1
 / \
2   5
   / \
  3   4
```

Can change only the values, so that in-order traversal will generate a reversed list:

```
  5
 / \
4   3
   / \
  1   2
```

This looks much better with binary search trees, but that is not the original problem description. With BST this reversal produces a BST with a reversed comparison operator.

Fortunately, usually *tree reversal* means a complete reversal of the tree, including its topology. It is fortunately, since getting a complete reversal is simpler to code than just value reversal. In the above example, a complete reversal of the original produces:

```
    1
   / \
  5   2
 / \
4   3
```

To get that you need to stop using a vector and stop collecting values. The algorithm becomes a trivial one-function recursive algorithm. It can be done with a function with a body of 6 lines.

If however you want to create a reversed copy, and not mutate the original tree, then it becomes a 7 line body.

Comment: Thank you so much. My approach was wrong. I have switched to an iterative solution using a queue where are switch left and eight pointer around. This has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Recursive Approach:

    public TreeNode invertTree(TreeNode root) {
        return invert(root);
    }

    public TreeNode invert(TreeNode root) {
        //base case 1
        if (root == null)
            return null;
        //base case 2
        if ((root.left == null) && (root.right == null)) {
            return root;
        } else {

            TreeNode leftt = invert(root.left);
            TreeNode rightt = invert(root.right);
            //swap nodes
            root.right = leftt;
            root.left = rightt;
            return root;
        }
    }
    }
```